# R Shiny - Dynamically show/hide editable datatables

Tags: r, shiny, datatables-1.10

I want to create a `tabsetPanel` that displays a selection of dataframes based on a `selectizeInput`, while also allowing for permanent edits of the data. I use editable `DataTables` to render the dataframes but couldn't find a way to save the edits. This example code illustrates my problem:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectizeInput(inputId = "dataframes", label = "select dataframes", 
                           choices = c("iris", "mtcars", "DNase", "ChickWeight"), multiple = TRUE, options = list(create = T))
        ),
        mainPanel(
            uiOutput("dataframes_rendered")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$dataframes_rendered =  renderUI({
        # create one tab per df
        tabs = lapply(input$dataframes, function(df){
            output[[df]] = DT::renderDT(get(df), editable = T, rownames = F, options = list(dom = "t"))
            tabPanel(title = df, value = NULL, dataTableOutput(outputId = df), br())
        })

        # create tabsetPanel
        do.call(tabsetPanel, c(tabs, id = "df_tabset"))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I understand why the edits are not saved in my example (the dataframes are re-rendered with every change in the selectizeInput) but, so far, everything I tried to to save the edits and re-render the editeed tables did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectizeInput(inputId = "dataframes", label = "select dataframes", 
                           choices = c("iris", "mtcars", "DNase", "ChickWeight"), multiple = TRUE, options = list(create = T))
        ),
        mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(id = "df_tabset")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    tables <- reactiveValues(
        iris = iris,
        mtcars = mtcars,
        DNase = DNase,
        ChickWeight = ChickWeight,
        df_tabset = NULL
    )

    observeEvent(input$dataframes, {
        if (length(input$dataframes) > length(tables$df_tabset)) {
            df = input$dataframes[! input$dataframes %in% tables$df_tabset]
            output[[df]] = renderDT(tables[[df]], editable = T, rownames = F, options = list(dom = "t"))
            appendTab(inputId = "df_tabset", select = TRUE,
                      tabPanel(title = df, value = df, DTOutput(outputId = df))
            )
            tables$df_tabset = input$dataframes
        } else {
            df = tables$df_tabset[! tables$df_tabset %in% input$dataframes]
            removeTab(inputId = "df_tabset", target = df)
            tables$df_tabset = input$dataframes
        }

    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE, ignoreInit = TRUE)

    observeEvent(input$iris_cell_edit, {
        tables$iris[input$iris_cell_edit$row, input$iris_cell_edit$col + 1] = input$iris_cell_edit$value
    })

    observeEvent(input$mtcars_cell_edit, {
        tables$mtcars[input$mtcars_cell_edit$row, input$mtcars_cell_edit$col + 1] = input$mtcars_cell_edit$value
    })

    observeEvent(input$DNase_cell_edit, {
        tables$DNase[input$DNase_cell_edit$row, input$DNase_cell_edit$col + 1] = input$DNase_cell_edit$value
    })

    observeEvent(input$ChickWeight_cell_edit, {
        tables$ChickWeight[input$ChickWeight_cell_edit$row, input$ChickWeight_cell_edit$col + 1] = input$ChickWeight_cell_edit$value
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I also made a change to your code by adding and removing tabs rather than rerendering all of them each time.

The `select = TRUE` takes you to the added tab but this can be changed to the default of `FALSE` to remain on the current tab.

The main way of saving changes is to use `reactives`/`reactiveValues`. See [DT Shiny](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html) and [examples](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-edit/).

**Update**

Based on the comment below, I now create each `observeEvent()` as needed.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectizeInput(inputId = "dataframes", label = "select dataframes", 
                           choices = c("iris", "mtcars", "DNase", "ChickWeight"), multiple = TRUE, options = list(create = T))
        ),
        mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(id = "df_tabset")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    tables <- reactiveValues(
        iris = iris,
        mtcars = mtcars,
        DNase = DNase,
        ChickWeight = ChickWeight,
        df_tabset = NULL
    )

    observeEvent(input$dataframes, {
        if (length(input$dataframes) > length(tables$df_tabset)) {
            df = input$dataframes[! input$dataframes %in% tables$df_tabset]
            output[[df]] = renderDT(tables[[df]], editable = T, rownames = F, options = list(dom = "t"))
            appendTab(inputId = "df_tabset", select = TRUE,
                      tabPanel(title = df, value = df, DTOutput(outputId = df))
            )
            observeEvent(input[[paste0(df, '_cell_edit')]], {
                tables[[df]][input[[paste0(df, '_cell_edit')]]$row, input[[paste0(df, '_cell_edit')]]$col + 1] = input[[paste0(df, '_cell_edit')]]$value
            })
            tables$df_tabset = input$dataframes
        } else {
            df = tables$df_tabset[! tables$df_tabset %in% input$dataframes]
            removeTab(inputId = "df_tabset", target = df)
            tables$df_tabset = input$dataframes
        }

    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE, ignoreInit = TRUE)

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a good start! Is there a way to observe the edits more generically without hardcoding the table names? I have potentially much more dataframes than the four used in the example, including empty dataframes that should be created when an new word is entered.